# i have imported a react component but it is not showing in page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/">
            <Login />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Login.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Login = (props) =>{
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content> content </Content>
      </Container>
    
    );
    
};

const Container = styled.section`
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: Column;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
`;

const Content = styled.div`
  margin-bottom: 10vw;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 80px 40px;
  height: 100%;
`;


export default Login;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Jvl.png)

the component Login is imported form Login.js but still there is no effect noticed in the content of the page.
i tried all possible solution but couldn't get a fix please help me out.

Comment: What react-router-dom version are you using?

Comment: If you look into your HTML elements in the browser, is the string `content` not there?

Comment: "react-dom": "^18.2.0" , yes the string content is not visible please check out the image attached

Answer (score 0):

Import BrowserRouter in your index.js file and wrap the app component with BrowserRouter.

```
<BrowserRouter>
<App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

And then remove the BrowserRouter import from app.js.
Import only Route and Routes from  "react-router-dom" in your app.js file.

The route path you have done has a mistake.

```
  <Router>
   <Routes>
      <Route path="/">
        <Login />
      </Route>
   </Routes>
  </Router>
```

Change this line of code to as follows .

```
<Routes>
<Route path= "/" element= {< Login/>} /> 
<Routes/>
```

This should fix the issue.